# Installing Mercury Editor on Rails 4 has returned routing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mercury-editor

After installing Mecury Editor, when I try to start the server I get the following:

```
in `normalize_conditions!': You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (RuntimeError)
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
  Instead of: match "controller#action"
  Do: get "controller#action"
```

Here's the routes file

```
Bootcanvise::Application.routes.draw do

Mercury::Engine.routes



  resources :newsletters

  resources :advertisers

  devise_for :users
  get "home/index"
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'home#index'
end
```

I've tried editing the routes file but i keep getting the same error

I expect it's to do with a lack of understanding for the routes.rb file.

Answer (score 5):

Today I had this problem too. It seems you installed an outdated version of mercury-rails.
Updating to master will fix this, so in your Gemfile change to this:

```
gem 'mercury-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury.git'
```

I had to empty my rvm gemset too. After running

```
rvm gemset empty gemset_name && bundle install
```

I had an up-to-date version of mercury and its dependencies and this error disappeared ...

Be sure to install version 0.9.0 as this is current master ...

PS: If you plan to run the images migration, you have to apply this patch here:

[Mercury pull request on #443](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/pull/443)

Comment: gem uninstall 'mercury-rails' worked for me, I didn't have to completely wipe out my gemset.

Comment: just run `bundle update mercury-rails`. that's enough

Answer (score 0):

**The route that your Mercury gem created is causing the problem.**

You need to modify the route that Mercury created (the current gem ...at the time I'm writing this) will do this for you:

In `routes.rb` change this line:

```
Mercury::Engine.routes
```

To this:

```
mount Mercury::Engine => '/'
```

After that you should be good to go!